# boundary imply positivity of solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the system of differential equations:

$x'(t)=-\beta x(t)v(t)$

$y'(t)=\beta x(t)v(t)-\gamma y(t)$

$u'(t)=b-(\mu+\delta y(t))u(t)$

$v'(t)=\delta y(t)u(t)-\mu v(t)$

with the boundaries $x(0)>0, y(0)\geq 0$, $u(0)>0$ and $v(0)\geq 0$.

I want to prove that this implies that $u(t)>0, v(t)\geq 0, u(t)>0, v(t)\geq 0$ for all $t>0$, how can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the signs of $\beta$, $\gamma$, $b$, $\mu$, $\delta$? If $\beta<0$ and $\gamma>0$ then taking $x(0)=v(0)=1$, $y(0)=0$ and whatever $u(0)$ you get $y(t)<0$ for $t>0$, at least sufficiently close to $0$. Further, what you call "boundaries" are *initial conditions*.

Comment: All the constants are strictly positive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us start with the $x$-coordinate.  The hyperplane $x = 0$ is invariant (that is, any solution starting on it remains there).  If $x(0) > 0$ then $x(t) > 0$ for $t$ sufficiently close to zero.  $x(\tau) = 0$ for some $\tau \ne 0$ is impossible,  since then some solution would, for $t = \tau$, take value on the hyperplane $x = 0$ and for $t = 0$ take value outside the hyperplane.  If $x(\theta) < 0$ for some $\theta \ne 0$ then, by the intermediate value theorem applied to the $x$-coordinate of the solution, $x(s)$ would be zero for some moment $s$ between $0$ and $\theta$, which has been just excluded.

Regarding the $u$-coordinate, again, $u(t) > 0$ for all $t > 0$ sufficiently close to zero.  Suppose to the contrary that $u(\theta) = 0$ for some $\theta > 0$.  Let $\tau$ be the first moment at which $u(\tau) = 0$. Of course, $\tau > 0$.  But then $u(\tau) = b > 0$, hence $u(t) < 0$ for $t < \tau$ sufficiently close to $\tau$.  Applying the intermediate value theorem as in the first paragraph we obtain the existence of $s \in (0, \tau)$ such that $u(s) = 0$, which contradicts the definition of $\tau$.

We have thus proved that $x(t) > 0$ and $u(t) > 0$ for all $t > 0$ for which the solution exists.  Now, fix some solution, and notice that its $y$- and $v$-coordinates satisfy the following system of *nonautonomous* linear homogeneous ordinary differential equations
$$
\tag{$*$}
\begin{cases}
y'(t) = - \, \gamma y(t) + f(t) v(t)
\\
v'(t) = g(t) y(t) - \mu v(t),
\end{cases}
$$
where $f(t) := \beta x(t) > 0$ and $g(t) := \delta u(t) > 0$. When $y(0) = v(0) = 0$ then $y(t) = v(t) = 0$ for all $t > 0$ for which the solution exists. If $y(0) > 0$ or $v(0) > 0$ (or both) then there is $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $y(t) > 0$ and $v(t) > 0$ for $t \in (0, \varepsilon)$.  Suppose to the contrary that $\tau \ge \varepsilon$ is the first moment at which one of the coordinates $y$ or $v$ (say $y$) takes value $0$ (why not both?).  Then $y'(\tau) = f(\tau) v(\tau) > 0$, which is impossible.

We have that the required inequalities are satisfied for all $t > 0$ **for which the solution is defined**. Now we need to prove that the domain of the solution contains $[0, \infty)$.  If not, the norm of the solution would blow up in finite time, say $T < \infty$.  Look at which coordinates may blow up.  The $x$-coordinate is positive and nonincreasing, and the $u$-coordinate satisfies $0 < u(t) \le u(0) + b t$. So, the blow-up of those coordinates is excluded.  Then the coefficients $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ in ($*$) are bounded on $[0, T]$, so it follows from [Grönwall's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality) that the $y$- and $v$-coordinates are bounded as well.